# Getting invalid callback using tesseract with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract

My error is:

> fs.js:132
>
> throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
>       ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
>
> at makeCallback (fs.js:132:11)
>
> at Object.fs.unlink (fs.js:1002:14)
>
> at /home/bakedpanda/Documents/BTP/node_modules/node-
>   tesseract/lib/tesseract.js:99:14
>
> at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:408:3)

Here is my code:

```
var tesseract = require('node-tesseract');

tesseract.process('cap.jpg',function (err, text){

  if(err) {

      console.error(err);
  } else {

      console.log(text);

  }
});
```

//cap.jpg is in the same directory.

Comment: Node should also point out the error line number. Can you put the entire error message?

Comment: check out now please

Comment: The problem was in the terassact.js file you gotta change fs.unlink(files[0]) to fs.unlink(files[0],(err)=>{ if(err){ console.log(err); } });

Comment: @CarlosAB Post that as an actual answer instead of a comment so that you can get reputation and so that there is a clear, visible answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the library on npm does not support Node 10 because of its deprecation of fs.unlink function without a callback argument.

A patch was already done to solve this issue, but this new version is not on NPM yet.